# Does Docker have the ability to run background tasks like Azure Webjobs?

Tags: docker, background-process

I've got a sorta-legacy R&D app which is a monolith website and then a few webjobs which are used for some background processing.

Now, I've been experimenting moving all of this over to Docker + Microservices (note: not because Microservices are the 'new hot stuff' but because our application suits getting split up into more manageable pieces/services.)

It was easy slicing the website up into Gateway API (or BFF Api's) + microservices. But I'm not sure how to handle the webjob migration. The webjobs are (currently) Azure Queue timer and trigger based.

Everything is running under:
- Docker (on linux containers)
- ASP.NET Core 2.1

Anyone have any suggestions what other ways I can migrate the WebJobs to a Docker container of something?

I know [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) is a tool that enables background processing on an ASP.NET website. But before I go down that route, just checking if there are other solutions people use.

Also, [.NET Core 2.1 has the concept of an IHostedService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.1) ... so I'm not sure if this is a legit solution and if so .. how?

Answer (score 3):

You can now run Azure Webjobs in a container.

If you target .Net Core and use [Azure WebJobs SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk) > 3.0 (Which is distributed as a .Net Standard 2.0 library), you can run the code inside a container. Use an image based on [microsoft/dotnet](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/dotnet/)

Here is an example in github: [christopheranderson/webjobs-docker-sample](https://github.com/christopheranderson/webjobs-docker-sample)

Answer (score 2):

Another option: [Implement background tasks in microservices with IHostedService and the BackgroundService class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice).

- This is for .NET Core 2.1
- Doesn't require a website (e.g. Kestrel on ASP.NET Core)
- Is basically a console app with some smarts to handle the lifecycle of your-tasks/your-services.
- Possible clean replacement for webjobs/functions.
- [Generic Host Code samples](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/tree/release/2.1/samples/GenericHostSample)

e.g a [really basic code example](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/release/2.1/samples/GenericHostSample/ProgramHelloWorld.cs):

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace GenericHostSample
{
    public class ProgramHelloWorld
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddHostedService<MyServiceA>();
                    services.AddHostedService<MyServiceB>();
                });

            await builder.RunConsoleAsync();
        }
    }
}
```